Quantum optimization: Number of needed auxiliary variables to reduce higher order terms
How many auxiliary variables are needed to reduce 3rd, 4rd etc. order terms to second order terms? Is there one formula for derivation?
What about when there is no 0:s and 1:s, but Hamiltonian and thus -1:s and 1s. Does number of auxiliary variables needed stay always equal to what is needed with 0:s and 1:s?

Optimization of what? At the moment your question appears very vague (at least to me). Can you please add some detail to clarify the exact setting you are thinking about.

Lets say we have the cubic term of binary variables $xyz$. We can reduce the order by introducing an additional binary variable, $w$, which we constrain to satisfy $w= y \times z$. We now replace $xyz$ with $xw + \lambda P_{w=y\times z}$, where $P_{w=y\times z}$ is minimized when $w=y\times z$.
A common choice is $P_{w=y\times z} = yz - 2wz-2wy +3w$.
We can do this iteratively for higher powers so a term of degree $n$ will require $n-2$ additional variables  to make the expression quadratic. There can be some further optimizations. If for example we have $Q = xyzt + 3xyz$, we only need to introduce extra ancilla terms for the first term and then we have the correct ancillas to let us represent $xyz$ for free.

How bad are those higher order terms for optimization typically? Do they "automatically" make problem signicifantly harder?
